# Running Spring boot via IntelliJ run configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have a small Spring boot application version 1.3.3 in IntelliJ 2016.1.2
Whenever I run the application via the command-line with mvn package && java -jar target/build.jar I can access the webapp without any problems. However, when I use a Spring Boot run configuration, the applications is started successfully, but when I go to the webapp, I always get the message 'GET' is not supported.

I recall that I searched for this problem some time ago and it was a known bug in the IDE that also appeared in Eclipse. But I cannot find those posts anymore and therefore cannot access the solution.

Can any of you guys help please?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if *application.properties (yml)* file inside *"Working directory"* of IDE run configuration. Or define it explicitly in IDE run configuration with *spring.config.location* property.
2. Check app startup logs whether declared request mappings appears, like so

> 2016-06-03 11:50:02,204 INFO  [main]
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]
>   Mapped "{[/webapp/1.0/endpoint],methods=[GET]}" onto ...